# How to add/update the mongo collections based on some fields using mongotemplate(Spring)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have one collection in mongo db with the following fields

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f370653368b91e7b932be3"),
    "_class" : "com.cupola.fwmp.vo.MaterialRequestVO",
    "ticketId" : NumberLong(12343545),
    "materialId" : NumberLong(43243545),
    "quantity" : 4,
    "usrId" : NumberLong(3535455),
    "addedON" : ISODate("2073-02-04T20:09:33.688Z"),
    "addedBy" : NumberLong(654661285)
}
```

I have to add the data into the collection if same combination of ticketId and materialId are not found, else I have to update.

After R&D I came to know that mongoTemplate.findAndModify() will be helpful.

Below is my code.

```
    Update update=new Update();
    update.set("quantity", materialRequest.getQuantity());
    update.set("usrId", materialRequest..getUsrId());
                    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("ticketId").is(materialRequest.getTicketId()).and("materialId").is(materialRequest.getMaterialId()));
mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true),MaterialRequest.class, MongoCollections.MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION_COLLECTION);
```

MaterialRequest.class is the entity

MongoCollections.MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION_COLLECTION is the collection name.

I am getting the following error message on adding duplicate data,

```
Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second 'materialId' criteria. Query already contains '{ "ticketId" : 12343545 , "materialId" : 43243545}'.
```

But if duplicate is there, Collection should update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code to do add/update operation.Its working

```
MongoOperations mongoOperations; //inject
    Query query = new Query();

    Update update=new Update();

    update.set("quantity", materialRequest.getQuantity());
    update.set("usrId", materialRequest..getUsrId());
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("ticketId").is(materialRequest.getTicketId()).and("materialId").is(materialRequest.getMaterialId()));

   long count = mongoOperations.count(query, MaterialRequest.class);

   if (count <= 0)
   {

    mongoOperations.save(materialRequestList,     MongoCollections.MATERIAL_REQUEST_COLLECTION);

    } else
   {

   mongoOperations.updateFirst(query, update, MaterialRequest.class);

   }
```

MaterialRequest.class is the entity class

```
Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second 'materialId' criteria. Query already contains '{ "ticketId" : 12343545 , "materialId" : 43243545}'.
```

Above exception was coming because, In a loop I was calling below statement

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("ticketId").is(materialRequest.getTicketId()).and("materialId").is(materialRequest.getMaterialId()));
```

for the same query object.

I resolved this by calling  Query query = new Query(); inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Mongorepository provided by Spring. This is the crux of the matter. Please check https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/ for more info.

Add this to your context:

```
<mongo:db-factory dbname="mongoDbName" host="mongoServer" port="mongoPort"/>


    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>
    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.test.dao.mongo"/> <!-- package containing all the mongo repositories corresponding to this connection -->
```

Use the mongo repository to find the JSON object based on your conditions. The method used to find requisite data will be as below.

```
public MaterialConsumption findByTicketIdAndMaterialId(long ticketId, long materialId);
```

Modify required data in the class where you perform update operations.

```
MaterialConsumption obj = repo.findByTicketIdAndMaterialId(12343545, 43243545)
obj.setTicketId(1231332);
```

Use the save() method in mongo repository. This will perform and upsert, i.e insert if unavailable or update if present.

```
repo.save(obj);
```

Comment: what repo refers?

Comment: thank you for your answer HARDI. tried your code and also I tried in another way , with out using findAndModify.

Comment: is it possible to do with findAndModify.

Comment: Did it work with the code supplied? I don't think findAndModify is a valid function for the purpose of your code. I tried with find and modify but it does not insert if the data searched in criteria is not found. It will work only if there is a data present with the criteria.

Comment: I am new to mongo. I din't understand properly. That's y I tried another way which I posted.